# Binomial tree in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

**Question**

Recombining tree solution with pgfplots (not pure TikZ).

**Context**

There are multiple posts on trees ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227414/draw-5-period-binomial-tree), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457603/draw-a-2-or-3period-binomial-tree), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522690/binomial-tree-in-tikz) and some more) and solutions are declined in multiple ways (matrix of nodes, trees, etc).
However I don't see solutions with `pgfplots`.

In `MWE` trying to adapt [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237483/how-to-use-tikz-and-macros-to-very-efficiently-draw-recombining-binomial-trees-w),I am stuck with the drawing of arrows in 2 ways.

1. first set of arrows going from left to right
2. second set of arrows going from right to left

[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 

    \begin{document}

    \def\mallevel{5} % a number of levels we wish to get

    \tikzset{
        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt, % some node reserve
        malarrow/.style={->, shorten >=0pt, shorten <=-2pt, -{Stealth[length=5pt, width=3pt,     inset=1pt]},
        }, % a style for arrows, -2 is a shift back (an experiment)
        malnode/.style={text=white,draw=blue!50, minimum width=5mm, circle, inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny,fill=blue,opacity=0.5,text opacity=1}, % a style for nodes
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xmin = 0,
                xmax = \mallevel,
                ymin = -\mallevel,
                ymax = \mallevel,
                xlabel = $x$,
                yticklabel=\empty,
                y axis line style={draw=none},  
                clip=false,     
            ]

        \foreach \x in {0,...,\mallevel}
        {
            \foreach \y in {0,...,\x}
            {
                \pgfmathparse{-\x/2+\y} % move up by a half of a tree (vertical direction)
                \let\movey=\pgfmathresult 
                \edef\temp{\noexpand
                    \node[malnode] (\x-\y) at (axis cs:\x,\movey) {{\x}-{\y}};
                }
                \temp

                %%%%%%%% draw the arrows    %%%%%%%%
                \ifnum\x>0 
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\x-1)}
                    \let\previousx=\pgfmathresult % previous level (horizontal direction)
                    \ifnum\y>0 
                        \pgfmathparse{int(\y-1)}
                        \let\previousy=\pgfmathresult % previous level (vertical direction)
    %                       \node[malnode] (\previousx-\previousy) at (axis cs:\previousx,\previousy) {check};
    %                       \draw[malarrow] (\previousx-\previousy) -- (\x-\y);
                        \fi 
                    \fi 
                } 
            } 
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your title should probably say `pgfplots`. I have to say I don't see why you would want to use `pgfplots` for this in the first place, it's not what it's intended for.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I’ll edit the title. I’d like to integrate binomial trees ro other plots.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to prefer `pgfplots` over `tikz` here ? By the way, your question is a bit confusing since both `pgfplots` and `tikz` layers come on top of `pgf` (they both use the `pgf` macros to actually plot, but provide a user-friendly interface)

Comment: @BambOo  I modified the title. I want to benefit from the axis environment, use groupplots  and add other pgfplots

Comment: There is still a mention to *pgf (not pure Ti*k*Z)* in your **Question** at the beginning. I have some difficulties  to see why making such a graph with `pgfplots` would work better than with Ti*k*Z. Both integrate quite seamlesly

Comment: @BambOo all corrected. I am not trying to have a better solution than TikZ, but I want to integrate this tree in other pgfplots, probably in background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you're doing, it might be better to do this sort of thing outside the `axis`. But anyways, you mainly just need to repeat the `\edef\temp{...}\temp` trick. And using `evaluate` you can simplify the code a bit, no need for the `\pgfmathparse` etc.

Don't know if the arrows are how you want them, but you should be able to fix that if not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 

\begin{document}

\def\mallevel{5} % a number of levels we wish to get

\tikzset{
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt, % some node reserve
    malarrow/.style={->, shorten >=0pt, shorten <=-2pt, -{Stealth[length=5pt, width=3pt,     inset=1pt]},
    }, % a style for arrows, -2 is a shift back (an experiment)
    malnode/.style={text=white,draw=blue!50, minimum width=5mm, circle, inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny,fill=blue,opacity=0.5,text opacity=1}, % a style for nodes
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = \mallevel,
            ymin = -\mallevel,
            ymax = \mallevel,
            xlabel = $x$,
            yticklabel=\empty,
            y axis line style={draw=none},  
            tickwidth=0,
            clip=false,     
        ]

    \foreach \x in {0,...,\mallevel}
    {
        \foreach [evaluate={
                    \movey=-\x/2+\y;
                    \previousy=int(\y-1);
                    \previousx=int(\x-1)}
                    ] \y in {0,...,\x}
        {
            \edef\temp{\noexpand
                \node[malnode] (\x-\y) at (axis cs:\x,\movey) {{\x}-{\y}};
            }
            \temp

            %%%%%%%% draw the arrows    %%%%%%%%
            \ifnum\x>0 
                \ifnum\y>0 
                       \edef\temp{%
                        \noexpand\draw[malarrow] (\previousx-\previousy) -- (\x-\y);
                        \noexpand\draw[malarrow] (\previousx-\previousy) -- (\x-\previousy);
                        }
                        \temp
                    \fi 
                \fi 
            } 
        } 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Merci ! I validated your answer of course.

Comment: The `evaluate` answers a long time question for me.

Comment: T. I'd like to use a circle split defining `malnode/.style={circle split,text=white,draw=blue!50,...` and replacing `\node[malnode] (\x-\y) at (axis cs:\x,\movey) {{\x}-{\y}};` with `\node[malnode] (\x-\y) at (axis cs:\x,\movey) {{\x}   \nodepart{lower}   {\y} };.` that leads to an error (`\pgffor@body... cs:\x`). Is the `noexpand` preventing the circle split ?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Seems so, the error actually becomes that `\nodepart` is undefined. I don't know how to solve that though, I suggest asking a new question.